# paypal checkout.js check error transaction

Tags: paypal, payment, checkout, credit-card

I'm working with the checkOut button (https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/confirm) and I'm having some trubles.
I have a question about the process of checking if a credit card is valid or if the account has enough founds for the payment. Take this code for an example:

```
  return actions.payment.execute().then(function(data) {

                    console.log(data);

                });
```

The question is that if I could know if 'data' has the information about the execution of the payment. If not, where I can find the information?

Answer (score 0):

If that `then` function is called, then the payment was successful.

```
return actions.payment.execute().then(function(data) {
    console.log('payment was successful!');
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log('payment failed!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but err doesnt contains denegate info. And onError event otherwise doesnt contain transaction info.